# Change the location of add_p() test labels

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

I have a series of `tbl_summary()` tables using `add_p()` to calculate p-values. I'm wondering if there's a way to specify which test is used for each p-value.

Currently, the list of tests used shows up in a footer line. Is it possible to change the location from the footer to the row?

I hoped it would be similar to doing `%>% add_stat_label(location = 'row')` but with the names of the tests generating the p-value instead of the cell statistics. Essentially trying to make it easier to understand which test was used for what p-value instead of combining them all in a list in the footer.

Comment: Could you add a MWE?

Comment: I think you just need to use this : https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/separate_p_footnotes.html

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg That's exactly what's needed! Is the location stuck to footer lines or can it be moved to the row with the p-value?

Comment: That function puts it in the footnote only. You can get the test name for each variable in the `x$meta_data` object